# What is causing this to fail to compile? Is it the declaration signature or is it within the implementation of the function itself?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, sfinae

I'm working on my `Component` class's member function `Component::connect()`. `Component` is an abstract base class for all other component types within my library.

I'm now in the process of modifying this method to make use of Variadic Function Templates and SFINAE to allow unknown multiple inputs into this function... All inputs must be derived from a `Component` type.

I'm having issues with the syntax for its declaration as well as its implementation... I've tried various things while getting various compiler errors. It might have something to do with Parameter Pack expansion or how I'm trying to use SFINAE within its signature.

Here is the current signature of my class and function that I'm working on...

---

```
class Component {
protected:
    std::string id_ = "";
    std::list<std::shared_ptr<Component>> components_;

    explicit Component(const std::string& id) : id_{ id } {}

public:
    virtual ~Component() {}

    std::string& id() { return id_; }

    // Trying to use both Variadic Function Template and SFINAE for this function!
    // I may eventually remove this from here and move it to another class using CRTP...
    template<typename ... Args, std::enable_if_t <std::is_class<Args...>{}, Component> = 0 >
    void connect(Args&& ...args) {
        for (auto& l : components_) {
            if (args->id_ == l->id()) {
                std::cout << "Component " << (args->id_) << " already exists in " << id_ << "!\n";
                return;
            }
        }
        components_.push_back( std::make_shared<Component>( args... ) );
        std::cout << "Successfully connected " << args->id() << " to " << id_ << "\n";
    }

    virtual std::list<std::shared_ptr<Component>> myConnections() { return components_; }
    virtual void propagate() {};
};
```

---

What would be the proper syntax to be able to successfully compile this in Visual Studio 2017 using C++17? I'm trying to utilize both Variadic Function templates with the use of SFINAE.

---

**Edit**

Before I changed my signature, derived classes such as `Wire` that are derived from `Component` I was able to use them like this:

```
Wire w1, w2, w3, w4;

w1.connect(&w2);
w1.connect(&w3);
w1.connect(&w4);

w2.connect(&w3);
w2.connect(&w4);
```

I would like to use this same function but in this manner:

```
w1.connect(&w2, &w3, &w4);
```

This is why I want to use a Variadic Function Template, and why I want to use SFINAE to make sure that any type that is passed into `::connect()`, in which all derived classes can use it, is in fact derived from `Component`!

Comment: As usual, please provide a [mcve]. Having four different code snippets that we need to recombine is not a minimal reproduction (and the vast majority of this code is irrelevant to the question).

Comment: @Barry, so combine them into one code block?

Comment: I provided the entire project... There is the main.cpp or driver application, and there are 3 header files! This is all of the code. The question is centered around `Component::connect()` in which I clearly described within the question! I'm trying to get the signature of its declaration right with the use of Variadic Template, and SFINAE...

Comment: I stripped out everything but the `Component` class itself... The question is centered around its connect() function that I'm trying to make as a Variadic Function Template while using SFINAE to make sure that all of the Variadic Parameters are derived from `Component`.

Comment: So, it boils down to [this](https://godbolt.org/z/ohsKte), right?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I believe so... most of the time, it's the syntax that throws me off with Variadic Function Templates... along with their parameter pack expansion... I just wasn't sure if it was coming from that or from the SFINAE... I'm not sure if it was coming from the signature of the function declaration, or from within the implementation...

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, well, that's the issue I'm having... and with Visual Studio's compiler errors, they don't give you much information... I'm not sure if it's within the declaration or within the implementation... and I'm not sure how to resolve it... Do I need to expand the parameter pack, do I need to use fold expressions and if so how?

Comment: I think fold expressions might help. Use a different compiler to test new stuff out quickly. godbold.com offers `g++` and `clang++` that both have very good compiler messages. With `clang++` I use `-std=c++17 -O3 -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat` which warns about alot.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo currently I can do this... `Wire w1, w2, w3, w4;` `w1.connect(&w1);` `w1.connect(&w2);` etc... I'd like to be able to do: `w1.connect(&w2, &w3, &w4);`

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's good and all, but I'm use to Visual Studio and my project is in Visual Studio. That's what I'm using to build and compile my program!

Comment: @FrancisCugler I added a demo to my answer where I used some of your code from an early revision of the question. It'd be great to hear if it works as expected.

Comment: @FrancisCugler I just found this old question when searching for answers on a similar topic myself :-) I never got any feedback regarding my suggested solution. Did you try it out?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> error: expression contains unexpanded parameter pack 'args'
>            if (args->id_ == l->id()) {
> ```

You could split up `connect()` in two functions to deal with the currently unexpanded parameter pack. One function that does the checking and connects and one that uses a fold expression:

```
template<typename T> // connect one only
void connect(T&& arg) {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<Component, std::remove_reference_t<T>>,
                  "Must be based on Component");

    for (auto& l : components_) {
        if (arg.id_ == l->id()) {
            std::cout << "Component " << arg.id_ << " already in " << id_ << "\n";
            return;
        }
    }
    components_.push_back( std::make_shared<Component>( std::forward<T>(arg) ) );
    std::cout << "Successfully connected " << arg.id() << " to " << id_ << "\n";
}

template<typename... Args> // folding
void connect(Args&& ...args) {
    (connect(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
}
```

Connecting would then be done like so:

```
w1.connect(w2, w3, w4);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4VYooS) (with bits from an old revision of your question)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand what do you exactly want (and without a full example is more difficult) but...

> All inputs must be derived from a Component type.

So, if I understand correctly (and given you tagged C++17, so you can use folding), the signature of the method should be

```
  template <typename ... Args,
            std::enable_if_t<(... && std::is_base_of<Component, Args>{}),
                             int> = 0>
  void connect (Args && ... args)
```

or maybe

```
  template <typename ... Args>
  std::enable_if_t<(... && std::is_base_of<Component, Args>{})>
      connect (Args && ... args)
```

> I'm having issues with the syntax for its declaration as well as its implementation...

About the implementation, I suppose the bigger problem is the cycle; maybe you can try with

```
     for ( auto & l : components_ )
      {
        std::string  aid;

        if ( true == ( ... || (args->id_ == l->id()
                               ? (aid = args->id_, true)
                               : false) ) )
         {
           std::cout << "Component " << aid
              << " already exists in " << id_ << "!\n";

           return;
         }
      }
```

or maybe

```
     for ( auto & l : components_ )
      {
        std::string  aid;

        ( ... , (args->id_ == l->id() ? aid = args->id_ : args->id_) );

        if ( false == aid.empty() )
         {
           std::cout << "Component " << aid
              << " already exists in " << id_ << "!\n";

           return;
         }
      }
```

or something similar.

But about

```
    std::cout << "Successfully connected " << args->id() << " to " << id_ << "\n";
```

frankly... I don't know.

Comment: I'll have to check this out when I get some time, but I already gave it an upvote from just a quick glance as it does seem helpful... It might help me to solve my issue(s)!